# In Lua with Canvas Draw, how do you use an origin from the top left?

Tags: canvas, lua

This is what is basically one of the Lua Canvas Draw demo gutted. It draws a 100x100 rectangle from the bottom left - the only problem is, if I resize the canvas to a smaller size vertically, it begins to cut off the bottom of the rectangle instead of drawing from a new origin, but only after a certain point. Is there a way to draw from the top left corner?

```
require "cdlua"
require "iuplua"
require "iupluacd"

function newWindow(w,h)
    w = w or 300
    h = h or 200
    canvas = iup.canvas{rastersize=w.."x"..h,border="no"}
    dialog = iup.dialog{canvas; title="canvas"}
    
    function canvas:map_cb()
        self.canvas = cd.CreateCanvas(cd.IUP, self)
    end
    
    function canvas:action()
        self.canvas:Activate()
        self.canvas:Clear()
        if self.Draw then
            self:Draw(self.canvas)
        end
    end

    function dialog:close_cb()
        self[1].canvas:Kill()
        self:destroy()
        return iup.IGNORE
    end
    return dialog
end


local dialog = newWindow(w, h)
local canvas = dialog[1]

function canvas:Draw()
    canvas = self.canvas
    canvas:Rect(0,100,0,100)
end


dialog:show()
iup.MainLoop()
```

This picture depicts two screenshots of the current effects in the right column and two pictures of the desired effect in the left column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Draw it at "y = canvas height - square height", i.e. `y = 300 - 100 = 200`.